# post image to facebook friend's wall

Tags: iphone, facebook, uiimageview, uiactivityviewcontroller

Im using `UIActivityViewController` for share image to social network. I need to post my image to friend's wall. Is it possible to post image to friend's wall using UIActivityViewController.

Comment: See, I have posted an answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

With `NSData`, you can add image to `UIActivityViewController`. Try below one.

```
NSString *text = @"your text goes here";

NSData *Da = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"], 1.0);

NSArray * activityItems = @[text,Da];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo]; //or whichever you don't need 
[activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {

}];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This code only post image to your wall.I need to post my friend's wall

Comment: How do you post simple text on friend's wall? Do same as you pass text, pass `NSData`.

Comment: sorry. I need to post text specific facebook url page. like this url: https://www.facebook.com/NokiaIndia. Is it possbile using UIActivityViewController.

Comment: I think using `UIActivityViewController`, you can only post on your wall, not on your friend's wall.

Comment: You have to use Facebook Graph API or Facebook SDK for this.